# On the usage of words instead of numbers to denote numbers

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

[To the best of my knowledge, I did not find any previous question that deals with this issue. I hope it is not a duplicate.]

I have a problem with the way in which mathematicians sometime use words instead of numbers to actually denote numbers. To me it seems that numbers should always be used *whenever we are actually talking about **numbers***, however it is not really the case.

**EXAMPLES:**
1) "Probability one" or "Probability 1"?
2) "Measure zero" or "Measure 0"?
3) "Solution larger than one" or "Solution larger than 1"?
4) "The value is one" or "the value is 1"?

In all these cases, I think the proper way of writing is the second one, however I often find the first way.

To me this looks particularly incoherent, because the same authors shamelessly move to the second style whenever the number is *slightly awkward* (i.e. it is not an integer). Indeed, it is quite easy to find somebody who writes down "probability one", and then later on writes "the value is $1/2$". [Please, note that I am not referring to a sentence like "the value of $\alpha$ is $1/2$", that can be easily rephrased in a more readable expression such as "where $\alpha = 1/2$".]

Here there are my questions.
1) Is there a general rule to write down numbers?
2) Is my intuition correct about the way in which things *are usually* written?
3) Is my intuition correct about the way in which things *should be* (on logical and grammatical grounds) written?

Thank you in advance for any feedback!

PS: True enough, the first and the second examples can be considered slightly different from the third and the fourth, because - even if it actually applies what I claim (i.e. writers use words to denote numbers) - those could be considered expressions that have developed historically an inner meaning that goes beyond the fact that they indirectly refer to numbers.

Comment: Be glad we are not required to say "unity", as mathematicians used to do when writing the number $1$ as a word.

Comment: In german I learned that only the integers $0,...,12$ should be written out as words, everything else should be written as number. But this is rather a general rule, an does even in german not necessarly apply to mathematical texts.

Comment: I think this has less to do about mathematics and more to do about writing style.  When I was going through elementary and secondary school, the rule of thumb was to use words for numerals less than 10, and to use the numerals for 10 and up.

Comment: @Hayden (and flawr): Yes, non-mathematical writing has general rules like this.  Kolmin says it is illogical for mathematical writing.  I say to Kolmin: go ahead and to it your way, but don't complain when others do it in other ways,

Comment: @GEdgar: I see what you meant. Thus my question is, which one of the two forms I presented do you consider good mathematical writing? (More or less in the same way in which there is *bad* mathematical writing for Serre).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a guide on writing mathematical papers [here](http://www.mit.edu/afs/athena.mit.edu/course/other/mathp2/www/piil.html) (about in the middle of the text) that has following guidlines:

> (...) In addition, avoid numerals because they slow down the reading. Write
>   numbers out if they can be expressed in one or two words and are used
>   as adjectives, unless they are accompanied by units, a percentage
>   sign, or a monetary sign. For instance, write, "The equation has two
>   roots," and "One root is 2." Don't begin a sentence with a numeral
>   or a symbol; reformulate the sentence if necessary.

Comment: Thus, the second way should be the *best* one, in terms of mathematical style as well, shouldn't be? Actually, it is a bit ambiguous, because in one line it says that the have to (note the imperative) be written out if they can be expressed in one or two words, but then we find "One root is 2". Now, this looks good to me, but it is slightly incoherent, isn't it?

Comment: The remark that "numerals slow down reading" is ridiculous. Generally, using appropriate *mathematical* notation (vs. natural language) *speeds-up* reading and comprehension (assuming a mathematically competent reader). I'd dread reading a paper in number theory written that way.

Comment: IMO, both yours and the site statement are debatable. It is true that mathematical writing is more about conventions than logical soundness, but still using numbers does not interfere with the quality of the reading and it is generally sounder (at least in the examples I wrote down).

Comment: I do not fully agree with @BillDubuque's comment. @ Kolmin: Yes it is coherent, since the author said you should write it out when the number if used as an *adjective*. The way I understand it is that they can *only* be written out when used as adjective. But I agree, I prefer numerals when refering to a value. (But not as adjective)

Comment: @flawr: It is interesting. I think we read the conjunction "and" in two different ways. I read it as the author was enumerating the cases in which you can use a numeral, that is: (1) when the number can be expressed in one or two words; (2) when it is used as an adjective. Thus, while I was reading the "and" as a logical "or", you were actually reading it as a logical "and".

Comment: Using natural language (e.g. English) instead of highly-optimized mathematical language is akin to riding a bike with training wheels. If you wish to excel at mathematics it is essential to train your mind to think in *mathematical* language, not natural language. With enough practice, one can *mentally* visualize an entire blackboard worth of grossly inefficient natural-language-presented mathematics.

Comment: @Kolmin Further, natural language may inhibit intrinsic mathematical pattern matching. For a simple example, compare: "in a domain, $\, x^{\color{#c00}{\large 5}}-a\,$ has at most $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ roots", vs. "five roots". Using *precisely* the same symbol $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ in both places helps the reader to see the relationship between the degree and the number of roots. In less trivial examples, such pattern-matching can be greatly obfuscated by the use of natural language.

Comment: @BillDubuque That's an excellent point about pattern-matching. And, sometimes, I try to make the text more structured/readable by, for example, using numerals for values and words for counts, for example: There are four cars A,B,C and D, with respective speeds (in hm/h) $50,60,70$ and $80.\quad$ I'm okay with this Answer's excerpt,  but its opening sentence indeed makes no sense unless changed to something like "In addition, avoid **a jumble of** numerals because they *slow down reading (and inhibit pattern-matching)*."

Comment: @Kolmin Both instances of "and" in the excerpt are meant as conjunctions; otherwise, the author's 2nd example ("write 'One root is 2'") would be contradicting their own advice to use spell out numbers in words whenever they can be expressed in up to two words.